# Function to convert array of heterogeneous variables to structure (preserving name)

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, data-conversion

I want to write a function that converts a **variable** number of variables (in the example below the array `sc`, the matrix `A`, the number `T`) to a structure that contains them. The respective structure labels should be the names of the variables themselves. See example below:

```
sc=[1 2 1 0.5 0.01 0.03];
A=[1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4];
T=2;
```

I want my function to do this:

```
data.sc=sc;
data.A=A;
data.T=T;
```

so that the output is:

> data =
>
> struct with fields:
>
> ```
> sc: [1 2 1 0.5000 0.0100 0.0300]
>  A: [2×4 double]
>  T: 2
> ```

for a **variable** number of heterogeneous arguments.

Comment: Splendid that you want this and present sample input and output, but what did you try to solve his? Please reread [ask]; the main thing you'll learn there is **show your effort**. Please [edit] the question with what you have already found out about this problem. If you have any code, please add that as a [mcve], and mention why your current solution doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I appreciate that, @Adriaan, but although I know how to write code given specific inputs and outputs (as included in my question), I have no idea how to generalise this to a function that takes a variable number of inputs. So I cannot attempt anything generic. I see that I might be using `varargin`, but I haven't been able to write anything complete and verifiable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function [`inputname`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html), in combination with [dynamic field names](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).

```
function outStruct =  dataStructifier(varargin)
    outStruct = struct;
    for k = 1:nargin
        outStruct.(inputname(k)) = varargin{k};
    end
end
```

This results in:

```
sc=[1 2 1 0.5 0.01 0.03];
A=[1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4];
T=2;

data = dataStructifier(sc, A, T)

data = 

  struct with fields:

    sc: [1 2 1 0.5000 0.0100 0.0300]
     A: [2×4 double]
     T: 2
```

Note that the function will cause an error when providing 'nameless variables', for example:

```
data = dataStructifier(sc, A, T, ones(10))
```

Comment: Thanks! This does not seem to work for a variable number of inputs, though.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you could use `varargin`, see my update.

Comment: Damned clever solution. To get around the noname variable problem, just put a 'try' command inside the for loop if that's important to you.

Comment: If you feel that you need to save that variable, Id' probably name it 'input3' or something - to represent which input it was. I guess it's all a matter of what usumdelphini has in mind.